# Positioning absolute items in a Bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to **Animate** absolute positioned blocks into a bootstrap col.

The issue is that the bootstrap col doesn't have a fixed width so on a different screen, all my absolute items will have a different

> What would be amazing is that if I set an element to for example: translateX(50%). It will always be in the center of my col-xs-4

[image]

#### Does anyone have experience with this?

### I've tried

Using transform:translate with percentages or pixels.

```
@keyframes animation {
    0% {transform: translateX(-100%) }
    100% {transform: translateX(0) }
}
```

That doesn't work because the percentage isn't based on the bootstrap col's width. So it's not responsive and with every screen size, ends up in a different place.

Comment: Where's your code? `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%;)` will center it horizontally in `.col-xs-4`

Comment: So where's your code? Without your code, we're just taking guesses. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your answer is correct! :) would you care to make an answer out of it? The code is very rubish so it's more a logic thing.. I'm trying to understand the left 50% and then the counter with -50% in translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%;)` will center it horizontally in `.col-xs-4`

Comment: Why is that? What does the translate(-50%) do? Thank you

Comment: @Notflip https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp